# Ag-grid cell renderer with slider not working

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am using Ag-grid with native JavaScript. I am trying to get a slider in a cell to work. 
I have implemented the cell renderer and used the jQuery slider inside it. However, the slider is not moving. I have tried stopping the event propagation with unsuccessful results. Any help is appreciated.

Here is a working example link. 
https://jsbin.com/netavepeme/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
  cellRenderer: function(params) {
    var sUI = "<div class='slider' style='margin:5px'></div>";

    // create jQuery slider
    var sliderObj = $(sUI).slider({
      min: 1,
      max: 5,
      step: 1, 
      value: params.data.val,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("slided");
      }, 
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("stopped");
      }
    });

    return $(sliderObj).prop("outerHTML");

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working

https://jsbin.com/coyakeluci/edit?html,js,console,output

So basically what I did is simply return the html inside the cellrenderer and onGridReady event that I added I initialized the plugin. I also removed your events that you added that prevent it to slide as well.

```
  cellRenderer: function(params) {      
    return "<div class='slider' style='margin:5px'></div>";
  }


  onGridReady: function(event) {   
    $(".slider").slider({
      min: 1,
      max: 5,
      step: 1,       
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("slided");
      }, 
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("stopped");
      }
    });
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although your approach works, I would prefer to initialize the sliders in the cell renderer. Do you know why the slider doesn't work when initialized inside cell renderer?

Comment: you should do it at the ongridready because that way the jquery plugin will find the html. There is no other way around that

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the existing answer not fully correct

First of all, you've mixed [`cellRenderer`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/) and [`cellEditor`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/) functionality.

`cellRenderer` - used for **RENDERING** (for displaying cell info, not for edit)

`cellEditor` - used for **EDITING** (which means, editor component would be accessible only when edit mode would be activated)

> So if you will try to get an updated cell value from `cellRenderer` it wouldn't be successfully achieved.

You can *play* with [ag-grid settings](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#start-editing) to get edit mode activated via a single click or additional key-press or even combine `cellRenderer` with hover logic to achieve instant edit mode activation.

**Btw this is how `slider` should be initialized in a correct way:**

*I believe that you already mentioned (from the links above) how you can create your own `cellRenderer` or `cellEditor` (in javascript) so, I will notice only about `slider` initialization.*

You have to define the `slider` after `Gui` is attached:

```
afterGuiAttached = function() {
    $(this.container).slider({
      min: 1,
      max: 5,
      step: 1,
      value:this.resultValue,
      slide: (event, ui)=> {
          this.resultValue = ui.value;
          console.log("slided", ui.value);
      }, 
      stop: (event, ui) => {
          console.log("stopped", ui.value);
          this.params.stopEditing();
      }
    });
    this.container.focus();
};
```

And also get&set `value` inside `slide` function.

<kbd>[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/S7aWWxnzU3fUwgqkZJrS?p=preview)</kbd>

*On [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/WLnL9snHo7UMIzQeDD7D?p=preview) example, you can find out how to create a component with enabled edit mode without single\double clicking*